# Changing end date to smart contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ethereum-classic

Newbie question.  Can someone walk me through the steps I have to take to extend the date to my smart contract from May 2, 2018 to August 2, 2018?

Like to try without asking my programmers for help.  Thanks.

Smart Contract is on etherscan.io and active.

TIA

Comment: Could you please post the contract code?

Comment: what d you mean by extend the date of your contract?

Comment: @Badr Bellaj Our ICO ends on May 2, 2018.  I want to change the smart contract code so our ICO ends on August 2, 2018.

Comment: @Henk https://etherscan.io/address/0x45edb535942a8c84d9f4b5d37e1b25f91ea4804c

Answer (score 2):

If you want to alter the end date of your token sale, call the function

`updateICODate(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime)` from the owner account, which probably is the account you deployed the contract with.

To do so, go to [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts) (please **DON'T** ignore any safety warnings from your browser). 
At MyEtherWallet, you can enter your contracts address, and its ABI. Then use [this website](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) to convert a start and an end date to the unix timestamp, which should be passed to the function.

After the transaction is mined, your ICO should be extended

Comment: @Henrk Thanks I'll give it a shot. Should be an interesting test of my skills. ;-)  BTW, can I use MetaMask instead of MEW?

Comment: You should use the combination of both: have metamask sign transactions you initiate with MEW